How to enforce typescript return type and disable implicit casting
i have this method which fetch data from an external api and return it.
the problem is that the data type being returned is incorrect
the function return type is IClickupTeam but the actual data returned is of type IClickupSpaces here is my code.
My question is how to  make typescript throw an error unless you validate the data
  export class ClickupService implements IClickupTeamService {
    constructor(@Inject(CLICK_CLIENT) private readonly _client: IClickClient) {}
   
    async findTeams(): Promise<IClickTeam[]> {
     const client = await this._client.getClient();
     const ret = await client.get('api/v2/team/9003054652/space');
     return ret.data
    }
  }

  export interface IClickupTeamService {
    findTeams(): Promise<IClickTeam[]>;
  }


Do I understand the question correctly? Are you asking "how do I validate that data returned from the network corresponds to a particular interface?"

@spender, my question is: is there a way to make TypeScript enforce manual validation for data that is only known at runtime? In other words, if manual validation is missing, I want TypeScript to prevent the code from compiling. Is this possible?

It's not possbile in typescript. If at all, it may be possible to define some linter rule. But honestly, I wouldn't know, how such a rule may look like. Because to typescript or the linter the client.get(...) is just a function like any other. How would you pinpoint, it needs a typecheck here?

The closest you can come is giving the function return type unknown which will give a bunch of compiler errors if you try to use the return value without validating it first. Also, @Inject isn't a node.js or Typescript feature, if you're using a framework either include the relevant tag or remove the code that isn't vanilla TS.

U could use type guards to check if type is desired but otherwise TS cannot do much for the return type

Please [edit] the code in this question to be a [mre] so we can copy and paste the code into our own IDEs to work on it. Right now you are using external/private things without declaring or importing them, so I get a wall of errors, none of which you're asking about. I don't know what client.get() returns, which is the crux of the issue, and without a [mre] anything people suggest will be something they can't test ahead of time.

The mechanism you seek from typescript can be achieved by enabling the noImplicitAny as well as the noImplicitReturns option(s) in your tsconfig.json file.
This will prevent typescript from allowing any as an acceptable type.

You cannot make typescript throw at runtime based on the response data from the API, however you can use typescript predicates to validate the data from the response, and use that to ensure the types are consistent for the caller of the function.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates
A type predicate is basically a boolean function that checks the object meets the type at runtime. Here is what that would look like:
const isIClickTeamArray = (items: any): items is IClickTeam[] => {
  if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
    return false
  }
  return !items.some(item => !isIClickTeam(item));
}

const isIClickTeam = (item: any): item is IClickTeam => {
  return true // return boolean check whether item is meeting the interface
}

export class ClickupService implements IClickupTeamService {
  constructor(@Inject(CLICK_CLIENT) private readonly _client: IClickClient) {}

  async findTeams(): Promise<IClickTeam[]> {
    const client = await this._client.getClient();
    const ret = await client.get('api/v2/team/9003054652/space');
    if (!isIClickTeamArray(ret.data)) {
      throw new Error(`Not meeting IClickTeamArray type`)
    }
    return ret.data
  }
}

export interface IClickupTeamService {
  findTeams(): Promise<IClickTeam[]>;
}

